# Keras LSTM model giving different predictions on same input when size of input has changed?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp, lstm

I am building a LSTM for text classification in with Keras, and am playing around with different input sentences to get a sense of what is happening, but I'm getting strange outputs. For example:

Sentence 1 = "On Tuesday, Ms. [Mary] Barra, 51, completed a remarkable personal odyssey when she was named as the next chief executive of G.M.--and the first woman to ascend to the top job at a major auto company."

Sentence 2 = "On Tuesday, Ms. [Mary] Barra, 51,  was named as the next chief executive of G.M.--and the first woman to ascend to the top job at a major auto company."

The model predicts the class "objective" (0), output 0.4242 when the Sentence 2 is the only element in the input array.  It predicts "subjective" (1), output 0.9061 for Sentence 1.  If they are both (as separate strings) fed as input in the same array, both are classified as "subjective" (1) - but Sentence 1 outputs 0.8689 and 2 outputs 0.5607.  It seems as though they are affecting each other's outputs.  It does not matter which index in the input array each sentence is.

Here is the code:

```js
max_length = 500

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000, lower=True,split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(dataset["sentence"].values)
#print(tokenizer.word_index)  # To see the dicstionary
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(dataset["sentence"].values)
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=max_length)

y = np.array(dataset["label"])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

import numpy
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)


X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_length)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_length)
embedding_vector_length = 32

###LSTM
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5000, embedding_vector_length, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
from keras import optimizers
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.9)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=3, batch_size=64)

# save model
model.save('LSTM.h5')
```

I then reloaded the model in a separate script and am feeding it hard-coded sentences:

```js
model = load_model('LSTM.h5')

max_length = 500

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000, lower=True,split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(article_sentences)
#print(tokenizer.word_index)  # To see the dicstionary
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(article_sentences)
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=max_length)

prediction = model.predict(X)
print(prediction)
for i in range(len(X)):
    print('%s\nLabel:%d' % (article_sentences[i], prediction[i]))
```

I set the random seed before training the model and in the script where I load the model, am I missing something when loading the model?  Should I be arranging my data differently?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I've been struggling with this problem recently

Answer (score 0):

When predicting, you always to fit `tokenizer` with prediction text, So print out `X`, maybe you find the difference between twice predicting.

The `tokenizer` in predicting should be same with one in training. But in you code, you fit `tokenizer` with prediction text.

Comment: Could the problem be with the tokenized dictionary (because it will be larger/different with multiple examples)? I'm assuming this would change the output since it has changed the features.  Would I need to standardize the dictionary to the one the model was trained on?

Comment: This is just my guess, because the gap of twice predicting is small and same time the difference between features in twice prediction should be small. Standardize the dictionary to one,  You can try it.

Do you know how to save `Tokenizer` model?  More commonly, We will save `Tokenizer` after training, and load `Tokenizer` when predicting.

Answer (score 0):

You're fitting a new **tokenizer** which is different from the **tokenzier** your model is trained on. So for that the first thing you need to do is to **pickle** the **tokenizer** and while prediction don't fit the **tokenizer** again use that **pickle tokenizer**
You can use that tokenizer directly as `X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(article_sentences)`
no need to fit again. I hope it helps!